# What is the correct way of implementing circular logic with the navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to implement circular logic with the Navigation component but I'm concerned that I'm not doing it right and lifecycle methods are unnecessarily being called.

I have 1 activity that has 3 fragments. Navigation between the fragments looks like this:
A -> B -> C -> back to A etc..

A and B are regular Fragments while C is a **DialogFragment**. C has two buttons - `Cancel` and `Done`. If `Cancel` is pressed, a navigation action is called (using `findNavController().navigate(<action>)`) and the app will show A. If `Done` is pressed, C is dismissed and the app will show B and the user can then return to A by pressing back. This all works as I expect, however...

My concern is that each route back to A results in different lifecycle methods being called in A. If navigation returns to A after the user accepts C and presses back on B, `onCreateView()`, `onViewCreated()`, and `onResume()` is called by A. **BUT**, if navigation returns to A after C is cancelled, A calls many more lifecycle methods (`onAttach()`. `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, `onViewCreated`, `onResume()`, `onDestroy()`, `onDetach()`). Why is there a difference? Why is onCreate() being called again in A? Shouldn't it just use the existing instance of A instead of creating a new one?

I can't figure out why it's doing this or if it's even something I should be concerned about. I'm confident that the stack is appropriately managed as the user navigates between fragments because the navigation action between C and A uses the `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` attributes (as recommended [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop) in the docs). I've also tried setting the `launchSingleTop` attribute in the action between C and A but I get the same behaviour (extra lifecycle methods being called in A).

Here is the xml for the C fragment:

```
<dialog
    android:id="@+id/C"
    android:name="C"
    ... >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/C_to_A"
        app:destination="@id/A"
        app:popUpTo="@id/A"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</dialog>
```

I call action `C_to_A` from C when the user presses the `cancel` button.

Any help clearing up my confusion would be very welcome.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `app:destination` at all on your action (instead of leaving that out and using `popUpToInclusive="false"` to create a pop only action)? Using `app: destination` means you're creating a new instance of `A`.

Comment: How would I get from C to A then? By calling findNavController().navigateUp() twice?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I just tried removing the destination attribute and setting popUpToInclusive to false and that seemed to work. A now calls the lifecycle methods I expect. I thought the destination would be required?! Thanks @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An action has two steps:

1. popping any destinations set via `popUpTo` / `popUpToInclusive`
2. Navigating (i.e., creating a new instance of) a destination set via `app:destination`

Actions can be any combination of just the pop, just the navigate, or both - the UI in the Navigation Editor when you right click a destination and select New Action will give you each of these options.

Therefore if you want an action that only pops back to a destination you know is on the back stack, then you can remove your `app:destination` attribute and only pop:

```
<action
        android:id="@+id/C_to_A"
        app:popUpTo="@id/A"
        app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
```

Note that by using `app:popUpToInclusive="false"`, you ensure that `A` will be on the top of the stack after the action is executed.